# Possible to intercept XMLHttpRequests coming from inside iframe (same domain)?

Tags: javascript, php, ssl, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I have a page that's loaded using https, and it embeds an iframe on the same domain, also loaded via https.

Inside the iframe, there are some XHR requests to an insecure http URL (the URL is actually to an IP address on the local network) that are being blocked.

Is there any way I can allow the requests to the local IP address? I only have access to edit the code in the parent frame. I can use php or javascript in the parent frame.

Comment: If it's in the same domain, can't you work with the owner of that page and get them to fix it to use HTTPS?

Comment: I think you could monkeypatch `iframe.contentWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` to make it change the URL from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: @Barmar the resource located at the local IP doesn't work with https :(

Comment: Then what do you mean by it's an insecure URL?

Comment: Oh, it's because the XHR is going to an IP, not the same domain.

Comment: You wouldn't even be able to make this XHR request from the main page, it doesn't matter that it's in an iframe. XHR has to go to the same domain unless the server allows it with CORS.

Comment: @Barmar yeah that's true (wouldn't be able to make the request from the parent frame), I just wanted to describe my situation in full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you recompile your browser, CORS explicitly prohibits this and no browser would allow it, unless the local IP machine returns valid CORS headers.

See here for CORS headers info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests